# How can you write to a database log only when the level is WARN in log4net c#

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to write to a log file and a database using log4net.  However I only want to write to the database if the level is WARN.

I have tried Threshold, level and filter in my config file.

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>

  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="WARN"/>
    </filter>
    <bufferSize value="100"/>
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <connectionString value="connString"/>
    <commandText value="APP_Insert_File_Failure" />
    <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />

    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@FileName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{FileName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>

    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@FileFailure" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{FileFailure}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="C:\Temp" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %newline%message%newline%exception%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

My C# code to run is

```
            //Parameters for stored procedure
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["FileName"] = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["FileFailure"] = "Testing 1 2 3;
            log.Warn("Testing 1 2 3");
```

I use to populate the connString -

```
    public static void SetUpDbConnection(string adoNetAppenderString, string newConnString)
    {
        log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
        foreach (log4net.Appender.IAppender appender in repository.GetAppenders())
        {
            if (appender.Name.CompareTo(adoNetAppenderString) == 0 && appender is log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender)
            {
                log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender adoAppender = (log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender)appender;
                adoAppender.ConnectionString = System.IO.Path.Combine(adoAppender.ConnectionString, newConnString);
                adoAppender.ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
    }
```

It writes to the text file no problem, but nothing is appearing in the database.

I want it to write into the database when level = Warn

Comment: The basic filtering is "at least the specified level", but do you want "only exactly the specified level"? Please explain in your question. Also add details about what you saw happening (or didn't see).

Comment: Is this a problem only with the WARN or others (DEBUG, ERROR) as well?

Comment: At the moment, everything s getting written to the text file, INFO, ERROR and WARN.  Nothing at all is getting written to the database.  I used <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
      <levelToMatch value="WARN"/>
</filter> in the database appender.  I only want level WARN to be written to the database, and everything written to text file.

Comment: It's not writing to the database at all, I removed the filter.  So nothing is getting written to the database and everything is getting written to the text file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the connection string.  I tried to change it dynamically, but that wan't working.  I copied the the connection string straight into the config file and it worked.

Now I just have to figure out to be able to change the connection string dynamically.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: It probably has to do with when log4net is initialized. Changing the configuration afterwards won't have an effect and not being configured before won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong when trying to change the connection string dynamically.

I changed -

```
 adoAppender.ConnectionString = System.IO.Path.Combine(adoAppender.ConnectionString, newConnString);
```

to -

```
 adoAppender.ConnectionString = newConnString;
```

In the SetUpDbConnection method.

Comment: Path.Combine is meant for filesystem paths (directory + file, for instance) - that's why it didn't create a correct connection string